# What's the -webkit-appearance for input type="number"?

Tags: css

I have an input like this:

```
<input type="number">
```

And my CSS has this:

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

So when I view it on webkit, the rocker (up and down) isn't showing.

I want to override this, what is the *default* `webkit-appearance` value for `type="number"`?

There are a ton of values listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance). Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmvzu2du/) for testing.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a completely viable question.

Answer (score 4):

When wanting things to return to default, `initial` is almost always the go-to value:

```css
input[type=number] {
  -webkit-appearance: initial;
}
```

> The `initial` CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element. It is allowed on every CSS property and causes the element for which it is specified to use the initial value of the property.
>
> – [initial - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmvzu2du/2/).

Comment: `-webkit-appearance` doing nothing with `input[type=number]`. It works with `input[type=number] ::-webkit-inner-spin-button` and `input[type=number] ::-webkit-outer-spin-button`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
-webkit-appearance: normal;
```